# Only Dummy Output in the sound

Tags: drivers, sound

In settings > sound > output i have only "Dummy Output"

I made a update & upgrade that break my screen resolution, but the sound was working, i solved reinstalling the drivers for Nvidia, but the sound is broken now

```
$ lspci -v | grep udio
  00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a3f0
  01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd TU106 High Definition Audio Controller

$ pacmd list-cards
  0 card(s) available.

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
  cat: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory
$ cat /proc/asound/
  cat: /proc/asound/: No such file or directory

$ dpkg -L linux-modules-$(uname -r) | grep snd
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-dummy.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-emul.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-event.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-virmidi.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-ctl-led.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hrtimer.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm-dmaengine.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-rawmidi.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-seq-device.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/pcsp/snd-pcsp.ko
  /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-ens1370.ko

* I tried

$ echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
$ sudo killall pulseaudio 
$ sudo alsa force-reload
  sudo: alsa: command not found
$ sudo apt-get install alsa alsa-tools alsa-utils
$ sudo killall pulseaudio 
$ sudo alsa force-reload
  Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
  Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).

Reboot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed this commands

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Reboot, and now its working